# Add ajax to plugin in admin area

Tags: ajax

I create custom plugin that to add new admin page ( payments settings) this page show all payments methodes with toggel to active and show setting button to this method or deactive it like this https://ibb.co/DQMVSYy
I have code to js file

```js
(function ($) {
    $(document).on('change', '.wsd-plugin-controller-toggle', function () { //checkbox
        let initiator = $(this),
            data = {
                'action_type': initiator.data('state'),
                'plugin_slug': initiator.data('plugin-slug')
            };
        $.ajax({
            url: plugins_controller.ajax_url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                data,
                action: 'myajaxfunction_check',
                nonce: plugins_controller.ajax_nonce
            },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', plugins_controller.ajax_nonce);
                initiator.closest('.wsd-toggler').find('.wsd-loading').toggleClass('visible');
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                initiator.data('state', response.state);
                if (initiator.data('reload')) {
                    location.reload();
                }
                $(document).trigger('wsd-plugin-state-updated', [initiator, response]);
                initiator.closest('.wsd-toggler').find('.wsd-loading').toggleClass('visible');
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log('error', response);
                initiator.prop('checked', false);
                $(document).trigger('wsd-plugin-state-update-failed', [initiator, response]);
                initiator.closest('.wsd-toggler').find('.wsd-loading').toggleClass('visible');
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

And in my html I have this

```html
    <td class="title">
                        My Fatoorah
                    </td>
                    <td class="status">
                        <div class="wsd-toggler">
                            <input id="toggler-csCeE5" type="checkbox" class="wsd-toggler-input  wsd-plugin-controller-toggle" data-plugin-slug="myfatoorah-woocommerce/myfatoorah-woocommerce.php" data-state="activate">
                            <label for="toggler-csCeE5" class="check-trail  wsd-toggler-shape">
                                <span class="check-handler wsd-toggler-handler"></span>
                            </label>
                            <img src="\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\plugins-controller\spinner.svg" class="wsd-loading" alt="loading">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="moderate">
                        <select class="wsd-payment-popup-select wsd-hidden" onchange="location = this.value;">
                            <option selected="" disabled="" hidden="">إدارة</option>
                            <option value="/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&amp;tab=checkout&amp;section=myfatoorah_direct">
                                الدفع المباشر
                            </option>
                            <option value="/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&amp;tab=checkout&amp;section=myfatoorah_v2">
                                كارت
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

All things as css code is work But I don't know what I should ADD in my action function `myajaxfunction_check` at my plugin  that to update plugin state and active/ deactive should I use api to do that ? I add this code but not working well

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_payment_style');
   function load_payment_style()
    {
     wp_enqueue_style('plugins_controller_style', plugins_url('style.css', __FILE__));
     wp_enqueue_script('plugins_controller', plugins_url('plugins_controller.js', __FILE__));
       wp_localize_script(
       'plugins_controller',
        'plugins_controller',
             array(
         'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
           'ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('plugins_controller')
          )
       );
  }

     function myajaxfunction()
    {
         add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ccbs_ajax_function', 'myajaxfunction_check');
           add_action('wp_ajax_ccbs_ajax_function', 'myajaxfunction_check');
       }
        add_action('admin_init', 'myajaxfunction');

        function myajaxfunction_check()
         {     global $state;
  
 
if( !empty($_POST['nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'plugins_controller' )
     ) {   
      $response['code'] = " sucsess " . $_POST['nonce'] .$state."active" ;
      
    } else {
         $response['response'] = "You didn't send the param";
            array(
                    'active'=>$state,
     );
     }

     header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
     echo json_encode($response);
  
     // Don't forget to always exit in the ajax function.
     exit();
 
  }
```

Thank you .

Comment: I mean to update the payment methode state not plugin

Comment: can you fix the indenting in your code? It's very difficult to read with broken indentation. Also, why are you registering your AJAX handler on `admin_init`? This is extremely unusual, I'm surprised it doesn't break your handlers. Have you considered using the modern REST API instead of the old legacy admin-ajax.php API?